# Does gRPC support wildcards (*) in the endpoint?

Tags: grpc

We are developing a gRPC service in Python. We got a requirement to support a wild card in the endpoint - something like `/service/qtom/*`.

Is it possible to do that or do we need to define RPC in the Proto file for every endpoint?

Is it possible to give wildcards in the gRPC endpoints?

Comment: What do you mean by "endpoint"? You mean the HTTP path? You mean the target name (similar to hostname)?

Comment: yes HTTP path.In proto file if i have a rpc then http path with be created with that rpc name `/JobManagementService/AnalyzeFile` ,wha we need is something like `/JobManagementService/*`

Comment: Have you find any alternative for wildcard

Answer (score 0):

You can create a grpc.GenericHandler and add that to the server.

Here is an example:
https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/python/grpcio_tests/tests/unit/_metadata_test.py

You will need to set the grpc.MethodHandler request_deserializer/response_deserializer to your protobuf serializers.